# Cycles rendering weird bubble shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, shadows

I have no idea what is causing this, but for some reason when I render my scene in Cycles it gives me these shadow spots. What's more weird is that it's *only* when I'm rendering interiors and it only shows up in the final render, the rendered viewport is perfectly fine.
[image]